# Using website IP address to view site

Tags: url, ssl, proxy, ip

I am trying to view a website using its IP Address, but failed to do so. What am I doing wrong?

The website IP address is provided in the image below.

[image]

Comment: How are you sure that there is a website behind this IP? When I telnet this IP on port 80 or 443 it doesnt respond...

Comment: The website is censored in certain location

Comment: Where is located you server? IPs beginning with '10.x.x.x' are generally in a local network...

Comment: can you tracert it and post here

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Webuzo or cPanel ?. If you have two IP addresses in one VPS, you have to try parking a secondary IP address in Webuzo or cPanel like parking a domain. I had tried this method if your VPS provider has supported it.

But now for me, my new VPS provider does not support it. I do not know why they do not support it ?. I have a feeling that my old VPS provider uses SolusVM and SolusVM has made default network so that we can park a secondary IP address in Webuzo or cPanel.

I also ask about that in this forum to build manually in CentOS 7 so that I can try parking a secondary IP address in Webuzo. I also hope get the answer in this forum.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cPanel then you can access it as IP/~cpanelusername

If you can provide more details regarding your webserver then it will help. Also, is the IP shared for other services?

Answer (score 0):

is it a dedicated IP assigned to the website ? if so you should be able to access the website with the IP provided its a dedicated IP assigned to it.